# Linking statements ending in question or exclamation marks in quotes

Tags: quotations, question-mark

Consider this:

> He began asking her rhetorical questions like "How dare you?", "How
>   could you?", and "How can you think such a thing?", but she did not
>   reply.

How can I write the above sentence correctly?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about where you should put the commas (inside vs outside quotes)?

Comment: Use of question and exclamation marks together is decidedly non-standard and is to be avoided in all but the most informal writing.

Comment: Laurel, yes.  Michael, I edited my question as per your suggestion.

Comment: I've read an article licensing 'double punctuation' where it adds clarity, but a caveat was that not all will consider it good style or even acceptable.